# Will it cause gradient vanishing by adding a constant positive and constant negative loss?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I want to ask a question about using two losses to train one model.
I am going to generate some specific kinds of question sentences.
To achieve it, I use 
(1) a normal GAN to generate the normal question space. Then 
 (2) an auxiliary classifier to let the generator focus on generating that kind of questions.

By pre-experiment, as I use BCELoss() on Generator-Discriminator loss (loss_G_D), the loss value is around 3.
And as I use -Entropy on Generator-Classifier loss (loss_G_C), the loss value is always negative, and very big, e.g. -300.
To not let them affect each other's training procedure, I used this training method.

```
optimizer.zero_grad()
loss_G_D = BCELoss(discriminator(generated_data))
loss_G_D.backward()
optimizer.step()

optimizer.zero_grad()
loss_G_C = -Entropy(classifier(generated_data))
loss_G_C.backward()
optimizer.step()
```

However, this training procedure is a little bit slow and seems like they put the network training 'back and forth'.
So a pal suggested me this method:

```
optimizer.zero_grad()
loss_G_D = BCELoss(discriminator(generated_data))
loss_G_C = -Entropy(classifier(generated_data))
loss = loss_G_D+loss_G_C
# if you worry about the scale, give some weight, like
# loss = loss_G_D+0.01*loss_G_C
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
```

I thought it makes sense. However, like the loss_G_D is 3, loss_G_C is -300, wouldn't it cause gradient vanishing by add them up? As using loss = loss_G_D+0.01*loss_G_C=0 ?
 Or can I say because they are different type of loss considering always positive and negative, we should not add them up?
(PS. I think maybe map the -Entropy loss into an always positive activation function, then add the two loss up will work?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it won't. In your case it is the total loss that is "vanishing", not the gradient. The gradient is simply the sum of the two separate gradients calculated from two losses. Since one loss is only enforced on `classifier` and the other one is only enforced on `discriminator`, back propagating the former should only assign gradients to `classifier` and back propagating the latter should only assign gradients to `discriminator`. So they won't affect each other.

Let me also explain with a simple example. Say you have only two parameters `x` and `y`. And you want to make `x` as small as possible by enforcing a loss `L_x = abs(x)`. Meanwhile, you also want to make `y` as large as possible by enforcing `L_y=-abs(y)`. So the total loss is actually `L=abs(x)-abs(y)`. Suppose initially we have `x=y=1`. Then the gradient is `(dL/dx,dL/dy)=(1,-1)`, while the loss is `L=0`.

More specifically, at `(x,y)=(1,1)`, `L_x=1` gives a gradient of `(d(L_x)/dx,d(L_x)/y)=(1,0)` and `L_y=-1` gives a gradient of `(d(L_y)/dx,d(L_y)/y)=(0,-1)`. You see that even though `L_x` and `L_y` cancel each other, their gradients don't.

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand that 'loss vanishing != gradient vanishing'. I think I can use the method 2 safely.<br> But if it is as you said, my pal's method (with # sign in the code) may be not so good right? XD. As he added up these two losses and backward it. Or will pytorch backpropagate each loss to their source even I did the sum? (maybe I should ask this question on pytorch forum ...)

Comment: Another question is that, I use two 'classifier' -- discriminator and auxiliary classifier to enhance the generator. But if as you said, it seems that I am training these two 'classifier'... I guess isn't there an extra step to bring the gradient from the 'classifier' to the generator? (Sorry for always asking rookie questions..)<br> PS: I set discriminator.eval() and classifier.eval() before training through...

Comment: I am sorry for my unclear first comment, I mean by your opinion, I can safely use `optimizer.zero_grad() loss_G_D = ... loss_G_D.backward() loss_G_C = ... loss_G_C.backward() optimizer.step()`, right? But how about add them up and backward? Will these two parts' losses correctly backpropagate to their sources respectively? Thank you!

Comment: @PeterNova Usually adding them is fine. It depends on how you implement the classifier and the discriminator, and also depends on what you put in the optimizer. But since your code is unclear about this, I can't be sure how your code would behave.